# ErrImagePull when running Airflow on K8s

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, digital-ocean

We run Airflow on K8s on DigitalOcean using Helm Chart. Tasks are written using `airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator.KubernetesPodOperator`. On a regular basis we see that pods are failing with the following messages (but the issue is not constant, so the majority of time it works fine):

We are using `KubernetesExecutor`.

Helm Chart info - `airflow-stable/airflow version 7.16.0`

```
Events:
  Type     Reason          Age                From               Message
  ----     ------          ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled       31s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned airflow/... to k8s-sai-pool-8c13r-9b9-8br6p
  Normal   Pulling         18s (x2 over 31s)  kubelet            Pulling image "registry.digitalocean.com/...:455eebb0"
  Warning  Failed          18s (x2 over 30s)  kubelet            Failed to pull image "registry.digitalocean.com/...:455eebb0": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://{URL}: unauthorized: authentication required
  Warning  Failed          18s (x2 over 30s)  kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   SandboxChanged  18s (x7 over 30s)  kubelet            Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Normal   BackOff         16s (x6 over 29s)  kubelet            Back-off pulling image "registry.digitalocean.com/...:455eebb0"
  Warning  Failed          16s (x6 over 29s)  kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

Comment: looks like the image is not publicly available as you get an "unauthorized: authentication required" message

Comment: It works every other time. So, 4 out of 5 dag runs are okay.

Comment: @StephenL. I have the exact same situation, were you able to find a solution ?

Answer (score 2):

That are most likely just DigitalOcean Registry issues
I suggest to try dockerhub